# Debugging WebAssembly

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, webassembly, vscode-debugger

I'm looking for a solution for debugging .wat files, which are WebAssembly Text Format files, preferably using Visual Studio Code. Does anyone have a recommended approach or extension for debugging .wat files effectively in VS Code or another interface?

I use Wasmtime in another related project, and it would be very nice to use the same execution engine.

I have looked into the LLDB but I have not found a good solution with a GUI. I have also looked into CodeLLDB vsCode extension but failed to configure it correctly.

I have a mac with Apple silicon but it also needs to work on Windows.

Comment: My go-to way for debugging wasm is to use Chrome's devtools which I find very user-friendly (although your identifier names may be removed). Unfortunately, I don't know of anything for VS Code or for Wasmtime specifically.